# Backslash issues when calling Linux commands via "os.system"

Tags: python

I need to execute the following in bash, but called from a Python script:

```
<command> --searchBody="{\"query":{\"range":{\"@timestamp\":{\"gte\": \"2020-10-16T00:00:00\",\"lte\": \"2020-10-17T00:00:00\"}}}}"
```

The double quotes must be escaped except for the ones that bound the `--searchBody` section

I have the following code in Python

```
execution = cmd+ ' --searchBody="{\\"query\":{\\"range\":{\\"@timestamp\\":{\\"gte\\": \\"'+startQuery+'\\",\\"lte\\": \\"'+endQuery+'\\"}}}}"'
print(execution)
os.system(execution)
```

`cmd` is the rest of the command already pre-populated, `startQuery` and `endQuery` are some date strings

The `print` statement prints the command exactly as it needs to, but when the `os.system` is run all the backslashes are removed from what is sent to the CLI.

I have tried all manor of escaping with multiple quotes but cannot get it to work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use `subprocess` module.
Try something like:

```
arg = '--searchBody="{\\"query\":{\\"range\":{\\"@timestamp\\":{\\"gte\\": \\"'+startQuery+'\\",\\"lte\\": \\"'+endQuery+'\\"}}}}"'
cmd = 'foobar'
subprocess.call([cmd, arg])
```

You should carefully read info about `shell` parameter and `shlex` module:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations

Using `os.system()` is like "I don't care about security, and all this crap, just run it"